# Showing equivalence of two bitvectors

Tags: dafny

I've been trying to show that two bitvectors are equivalent when all its individual bits are equivalent. In other words, the following statement where `a` and `b` are `bv64` and `BitIsSet` is a function extracting the `ith` bit from the bitvector, and `WORD_SIZE` is 64.

```
(a == b) == (forall i | 0 <= i < WORD_SIZE :: (BitIsSet(a, i) == BitIsSet(b, i)))
```

The first case, where `a == b` seems trivial for Dafny. So what I'm left to show is that

```
if a != b {
    assert !(forall i | 0 <= i < WORD_SIZE :: (BitIsSet(a, i) == BitIsSet(b, i)));
}
```

which basically is showing that there exists an `i` such that the two bits are different:

```
    assert exists i | 0 <= i < WORD_SIZE :: (BitIsSet(a, i) != BitIsSet(b, i))
```

Any hints on how to best go about this?

For completeness, `BitIsSet` basically masks the bit at `ith` position and compares it against 0.

```
predicate method {:opaque} BitIsSet(x:bv64, i: nat)
    requires i < WORD_SIZE
{
   (x & ((1 as bv64) << (i as bv7))) != 0
}
```

The same thing by using sequences of booleans seems to be pretty much trivial,
I suspect that there is some kind of axiom being used?

```
lemma SeqBoolEquiv(a: seq<bool>, b: seq<bool>)
    requires |a| == WORD_SIZE && |b| == WORD_SIZE
    ensures (a == b) <==> (forall i | 0 <= i < WORD_SIZE :: a[i] == b[i])
{
}
```

Edit: Trying to understand what's going on here: Would the inability to show equivalence for bitvectors (as opposed to sequences) likely be due to a missing axiom at Dafny level, or some possible limitations at Boogie or Z3 showing equivalence of bitvectors there?

Comment: I tried using a while loop but did not succeed yet. However, it enabled me to find a soundness issue that I filed.
https://github.com/dafny-lang/dafny/issues/2511

Comment: Oh, that's an interesting. I'm glad that my question helped to reveal a bug.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've managed to do the proof, roughly following the proof of a colleague in a different Language. So, Dafny is happy to show that

```
(a & 0xffff_ffff_ffff_ffff) == (b & 0xffff_ffff_ffff_ffff) <==> a == b
```

We can use this and do induction over the bitmask, converting our initial proof into:

`((a & Bitmask(N)) == (b & Bitmask(N)) == (forall i | 0 <= i < N :: (BitIsSet(a, i) == BitIsSet(b, i)))`

then do induction over `N` with base case `N == 0` where `Bitmask(0) == 0`, and show the step case reasoning about the additional bit.

Finally, we can use the induction proof to get the result for `N == WORD_SIZE` which gives us the original lemma as `(a & Bitmask(WORD_SIZE)) == a`.

EDIT: The BitMask definition. Does rely on overflow to get `BitMask(64)` working, i.e., it shifts the `1` out of the `bv64`, then `0 - 1 == 0xff..ff`. Dafny seems happy with it, and I can show that `BitMask(WORD_SIZE) == 0xff..ff`

```
    function method {:opaque} BitMask(i: uint64) : bv64
        requires i <= WORD_SIZE
    {
        ((1 as bv64) << (i as bv7)) - 1
    }
```

Comment: Great solution. How do you define `Bitmask`?

Comment: Adding the definition of the BitMask function.